# Howto: Count the amount of words in one column

Tags: mysql

In my MYSQL-table I have a column in which are text elements and dates (1994, 1995, ...2019). 
I would like to count how often a special year (let's say 2006) can be found (not in one line but in the whole column).
It is possible that a year can be found in one line one time, several times or maybe not.

I have no idea how to code in MYSQL.

Thanks for your help !
Maik

Comment: select count(*) from table where column like `%2006%` ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the occurences of a string in a string is a little tricky. You can replace the string of which you want to get the occurences of in the string you want to count these occurences in. If you then devide the difference in length of the original string and the string `replace()` returned by the length of the length of the string you want to get the occurrences of, you got the number of occurrences. To sum this over all rows you can simply use `sum()`.

```
SELECT sum((length(nmuloc)
            - length(replace(nmuloc,
                             '2006',
                             '')))
            / length('2006')) occurrences
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that idea, seems to be great. But how to get the amount ? Do I need $q="SELECT sum((length(fotos) - length(replace(fotos, '2019', ''))) / length('2019')) FROM register;";
$www= mysql_query($q);

$numb=mysql_num_rows($www); ? Or how can I get the result ??? So sorry, I'm just a newbee....

Comment: @Maik: Well, that's a PHP question. In general you'd execute the query and then get the result. Note, that `mysql_` functions are long deprecated in PHP and shouldn't be used anymore. Also you need to get the actual result, not the number of rows of the result (which will always be one). On how to retrieve data with a query from a MySQL in PHP, there's a lot of tutorials our there. You will find the answer on the details there. Just use a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am assuming that you have stored only the year and so the data type of that column is TEXT and not DATE. For this use the following query:
(Say the column containing the years is named year_col)

```
select count(year_col) from <table name> where year_col='2006' ;
```

While if the data type is DATE then consider the following query:

```
select count(year_col) from <table name> where year(year_col)='2006';
```

You can learn more about the count() function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially try a like statement.

If the value in the column only contained the year, then you would use your standard `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from TableName WHERE ColumnName = '2006'
```

Assuming your column is a text string, you may be interested in a  `WHERE LIKE` clause with wild cards:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%2006%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am building off of sticky bit's answer (which I think is the way to go) to see if using `GROUP_CONCAT` offers any performance improvement at all. The `/4` indicates length of "2006"

```
SELECT     
(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(Column_Name))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(Column_Name),'2006','')))/4 
AS Count_String
FROM YourTable;
```